# Ruby prevent default CTRL+C output ^C

Tags: ruby, signals, rescue

I am catching signal with

```
rescue Interrupt => e
```

But it always prints:

```
^CShutting down!
```

Is there a way to prevent the default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> output:

```
^C
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by catching the signal? It is possible (and relatively easy) to ignore the signal, but might be a little harder if you need a controlled shutdown, just without the message. It looks like some other library is displaying the message, and might be expecting to perform a shutdown.

Comment: Could you clarify whether it is your code writing "Shutting down!" - i.e. you want that message, just not the `^C` echoed to the terminal?

Comment: yes my code does puts "Shutting down." When signal received, my code cancels current processes, saves the progress, puts "Shutting down" and exit 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some terminals support `stty -echoctl` to disable echoing of control characters:

```
`stty -echoctl`

begin
  loop do
    # ...
  end
rescue Interrupt => e
  puts 'shutting down'
end
```

If the above doesn't work, you can disable all echoing by setting [`IO#echo=`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-echo-3D) to `false`:

```
require 'io/console'

STDIN.echo = false

begin
  loop do
    # ...
  end
rescue Interrupt => e
  puts 'shutting down'
end
```

Comment: Perfect second suggestion worked like a charm. Cheers, appreciate it!